# How to check if DateTime is null

Tags: c#, datetime, null, calendar

I have my two `DateTime` as follow:

```
        DateTime startDate = CalendarFrom.SelectedDate;
        DateTime endDate = CalendarTo.SelectedDate;
```

Now, I want to check if the `startDate` and `endDate` is selected or not. As I know, we cannot assign null to `DateTime` so I write in this way:

```
       if (startDate == DateTime.MinValue && endDate == DateTime.MinValue)
       {
             // actions here
       }
```

However I realise that for the `endDate`, it is not "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" so it cannot be checked by using `DateTime.MinValue`.

I would like to know how will I be able to do checking for the `endDate`. Thanks!

Comment: In that case where the date you want to reprisent as null is returned as NOT DateTime.MinValue. Then use a constant to represent the value which DOES correspond to null in the Calendar control you are using.

Answer (score 13):

A `DateTime` itself can't be null - it's cleanest to use `DateTime?` aka `Nullable<DateTime>` to represent nullable values.

It's not clear what `CalendarFrom` and `CalendarTo` are, but they may not support `Nullable<DateTime>` themselves - but it would be a good idea to centralize the conversion here so you can use `Nullable<DateTime>` everywhere *other* than where you're directly using `CalendarFrom` and `CalendarTo`.

Answer (score 4):

`DateTime` is a struct and so it can never be null.

I can think of two options:

1. If you really want to support null, use `DateTime?` to create a nullable DateTime.
2. Alternatively, it may be appropriate in your application to simply set a `DateTime` value to a default value that indicates no real value has been set. For this default value, you could use either `default(DateTime)` or something like `DateTime.MinValue`.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what are your CalenderFrom and CalenderTo are; but I am assuming that they  are static classess. Based on that assumption,  this is how I would write this code.

```
public static class CalendarFrom
{
    public static DateTime SelectedFrom { get; set; }
}

public static class CalendarTo
{
    public static DateTime SelectedDate { get; set; }
}

DateTime? startDate = CalendarFrom.SelectedFrom;
            DateTime? endDate = CalendarTo.SelectedDate;

            if (startDate.HasValue 
                && ( startDate.Value != DateTime.MaxValue || startDate.Value != DateTime.MinValue))
            {
            }
```